# CF2018 (HF7) IIS / W2K16 - cfoutput in email templates is not rendering

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2018

We have 3 servers – production (CF2016 HF4), staging (2018.0.07.316715) and I have a local install on my Windows 10 desktop (2018.0.07.316715).

All were setup following the lockdown guide.

We have thousands of e-mail templates stored as .htm files which are included as a cfinclude or savecontent in cfmail.  The .htm files generally have a few cfoutputs and several cfincludes that bring in other pieces of templates.

On staging, none of the CF in the templates are working.  Includes are skipped and output is just #output#.

Permissions seem the same on folders, so I’m thinking this may have something to do with an IIS handler or mapping to Jakarta issue, but I'm not sure where to start to troubleshoot this one.

Comment: Check to ensure that on the staging server, ColdFusion code in .htm files get processed.

Comment: It does not get rendered if I add CF to a .htm and call the file in a browser.  What's weird is I don't recall every adding or changing anything to get that to work before.

Comment: Look at the html source code in your browser.  Are the CFML tags there?

Comment: Off topic, but I'd note that if you are on CF2016 HF4, you should look at applying subsequent hotfixes. There were a lot of security issues fixed between HF4 and now.

Comment: It looks like IIS on Staging isn't set up to process .htm files through CF.

Comment: @Shawn - CF2016 was has HF11, it's now HF13.  CF2018 was has HF4 and is now HF7.  Found the setting that changed in cfadmin for the allowed into includes as well.

Answer (score 2):

In CF2018 Admin on the Settings page is a list of file extensions that are allowed to be included using cfinclude.  Somewhere between install dates of these servers the default of CFM, CFML, HTM, HTML was changed to just CFM, CFML.  Adding HTM and HTML into the problematic server fixed that issue.